# ElasticSearch: How to query in sub-groups?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which stores the skills a user knows:

```
{
"size": 1000,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "Objective-C",
                            "default_field": "user.skill.name"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "user.skill.weight_relative": {
                                "gte": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "user.skill.weight_absolute": {
                                "gte": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
...
```

Problem I'm experiencing is that ElasticSearch is returning users with, for example, `skill.name == Objective-C` but the weight is 0 for both relative and absolute, and also users with scores gte than 1, but the skill.name is something completely different.

Is there any way to tell elastic that I wan't those searches to be "locally" scoped? I don't know the name of this scenario. Excuse me if I'm not calling it properly.

The query I'm running, also has a custom _score function, which gives higher score to users with a third metric (not including as its not relevant). May it be because of this custom score function? May it be giving the "wrong" users a higher score because of the third metric being higher that the users with the desired skills and level?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem completely, but it looks like you want 'must' clause instead of 'should'

Comment: Do keep in mind that the `should` clause can be thought of as a boolean `OR` (and not `AND`, which is more of what `must` implements) - I think by default, any document satisfying one (and it can be any one) of those conditions will match, although this requirement could be explicitly specified by `minimum_should_match`. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replying. It can't be a `must` because the `should` condition is only there to add score. Imagine a user has 0 weight on a skill, it still should appear, but lower.

Comment: Thanks @rchang, if I just could specify WHICH one should at least match, that would be perfect, as I'd need at least the skill name to match, the rest shoulds are just adding score: more score, the higher they come

Comment: I will explain again my scenario:

I may be searching by many skills, so Objective-C, Swift, Cocoa. So I can't put the skill name as a "must", because some users may just have one of them, but that should be OK. I just then need that the weight is from that skill and not of some other: I may have 2 skills - Swift and Python. I have weight in Python, not in Swift. This should NOT give higher score to the user because the weight corresponds to the "wrong" skill.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

Had to change the type of the element from `object` to `nested` and perform a `nested` search. The example in the link shows exactly what I was experiencing.